# How do I select the longest 'string' from a table when grouping

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
SELECT partnumber, manufacturer, condition, SUM(qty), AVG(price), description FROM parts

WHERE [something]

GROUP BY partnumber, manufacturer, condition
```

I have some descriptions that are blank, and there can be many partnumber, manufacturer, condition values, and on the group it seems to take the first description available, which can be blank.  I'd like to get the longest description available.

I tried this:

```
MAX(LENGTH(description))
```

however, that returns the number of characters in the string.  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in MySQL?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Try `ORDER BY LENGTH(description) DESC` and use `LIMIT 1` to only get the largest.

Answer (score 31):

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(description) DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will sort the results from longest to shortest and give the first result (longest.)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT   partnumber, manufacturer, `condition`, SUM(qty), AVG(price), description
FROM     parts
WHERE    [something] AND LENGTH(description) = (
           SELECT MAX(LENGTH(description))
           FROM   parts AS p
           WHERE  p.partnumber   = parts.partnumber
              AND p.manufacturer = parts.manufacturer
              AND p.condition    = parts.condition
         )
GROUP BY partnumber, manufacturer, `condition`
```

Comment: This seems to me to 'expensive', in running time and written code, for the selection of one record. I don't think a sub-query is the best way to handle the problem.

Comment: @rosa: you're right about verbosity, though I'm not sure performance time would be greatly different (both this and ORDER BY require filesort).  Advantage of this version is that it returns all records of maximal length, not just a single indeterminate one.

Comment: @rosa: also, looking back over this question, I think my understanding was that the OP wanted to obtain the longest string in each group, rather than the longest result overall.

Answer (score 4):

`MAX(LENGTH(description))` returns length of longest value in Description column.

Answer (score 3):

If a "description" contains multi-idiom characters, then you should use

```
MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(description))
```

For example :

```
SELECT LENGTH("Это тест, связанный с длиной строки в базе данных")
```

Resulting in 89.

Whereas :

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH("Это тест, связанный с длиной строки в базе данных")
```

Resulting in 49.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. `MAX(description)` seems to work just fine.

Comment: That won't give you the *longest* description, rather the description which is the lexical maximum (i.e. in an alphabetical ordering).  However, since that ordering will place any non-empty description after empty ones, it will always result in a non-empty description if one exists: perhaps this is sufficient for your needs?