# Select a string with max length while using Group by in data table in r

Tags: r, data.table, greatest-n-per-group

My initial sample data was ambiguous **so updating my data set**

```
a <- data.table(name=c("?","","One","?","","Two"), value=c(1,3,2,6,5,2) , job=c(1,1,1,2,2,2) )

 name value job
1:    ?     1   1
2:          3   1
3:  One     2   1
4:    ?     6   2
5:          5   2
6:  Two     2   2
```

I want to group by the column "job" while finding the maximum in column "value" and selecting the "name" which has the maximum length.

My sample output would be

```
   name job value
1: One    1     3
2: Two    2     6
```

I think I want the equivalent of  [How do I select the longest 'string' from a table when grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882679/how-do-i-select-the-longest-string-from-a-table-when-grouping) in R

Comment: Please note that apart from the longest text, I also want to find max of "value" I have updated my sample data set now.

Comment: The usual duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16573995

Comment: @Frank please read through completely before posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'job', get the index of the `max` number of characters (`nchar`) in 'name' and subset the dataset.

```
a[, .SD[which.max(nchar(name)) ], by = job]
#    name value job
#1:  One     3   1
#2:  Two     6   2
```

Or get the row index (`.I`) from `which.max`, extract the column with the index ("V1") and subset the dataset.

```
a[a[, .I[which.max(nchar(name))], by = job]$V1]
```

#### Update

Based on the new example, if the 'value' is not corresponding to the maximum number of character in 'name', we need to select it separately.

```
a[, .(value= max(value), name = name[which.max(nchar(name))]),
                      by = job]
#     job value name
#1:   1     3  One
#2:   2     6  Two
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Your solution will not work in cases where max(value) lies in other positions. I have updated my sample data set now.

Comment: This is brilliant!! I dint know this was possible!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you want a dplyr solution but here is one:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% group_by(job) %>% slice(which.max(nchar(as.character(name))))

    name value   job
  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1    One     3     1
2    Two     6     2
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Your solution will not work in cases where max(value) lies in other positions. I have updated my sample data set now.

Comment: @pauljeba The fix is obvious based on what you saw in the other answer: switch max to which.max. If you're going to edit your question to invalidate an answer, feel free to "fix" the answer to match your edited question.

Comment: @Frank I dint change the question, just gave a clearer example. Thank you for your suggestion.